# close current popup upon file download dialog is shown

Tags: javascript, file, download, popup

I have tried to search the solution but could not get any relevant answer. I want to close the current popup once File download popup opens in the browser. For example, in the source code below if i write "window.close()" after ajax request then file download popup is never shown.

But once i remove this line then file download works but how would i close the current popup?

My use case is:

**main.php**

```
<script>
    window.open('popup.php','redirect','width=500,height=500');
</script>
```

**popup.php**

```
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        var url = 'download.php';
        var output_type = 'xls';
        params = "function=execute_cache&output="+output_type;
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: url,
            data: params,
            success: function(response, status, request) {
                var disp = request.getResponseHeader('Content-Disposition');
                if (disp && disp.search('attachment') != -1) {
                    var form = $('<form method="POST" action="' + url + '">');
                    $.each(params, function(k, v) {
                        form.append($('<input type="hidden" name="' + k +
                                '" value="' + v + '">'));
                    });
                    $('body').append(form);
                    form.submit();
                }
            }
        });
        window.close();
    </script>
</body>
```

**download.php**

```
<?php
$handle = fopen("file.txt", "w");
fwrite($handle, "text1.....");
fclose($handle);
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename('file.txt'));
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
header('Pragma: public');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize('file.txt'));
readfile('file.txt');
exit;
```

**Note:** I can not use setTimeout function to auto close popup because i do not know in how much time file will be downloaded. So i can not give a maximum time. The code shown in download.php is not an actual code. Actually, i would fetch huge data and generate XLS.

I just want to get current popup closed automatically as soon as File download popup is shown to user to download the file.

Comment: give a id to `window.open` like `windowPopup = window.open('popup.php','redirect','width=500,height=500');` and use `windowPopup.close();` . to close ince you get the result in xhr request.

Answer (score 0):

use **promise** to do such async calls. learn more about it https://www.sitepoint.com/overview-javascript-promises/

also give a id to window.open like

`windowPopup = window.open('popup.php','redirect','width=500,height=500');`

and use

`windowPopup.close();`

```
var windowPopup = window.open('popup.php','redirect','width=500,height=500');

    function callRequest () {
      return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        var url = 'download.php';
        var output_type = 'xls';
        var params = "function=execute_cache&output="+output_type;

        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open('POST', url, param);
        xhr.onload = function () {
          if (this.status >= 200 && this.status < 300) {
              var disp = request.getResponseHeader('Content-Disposition');
              if (disp && disp.search('attachment') != -1) {
                  var form = $('<form method="POST" action="' + url + '">');
                  $.each(params, function(k, v) {
                      form.append($('<input type="hidden" name="' + k +
                              '" value="' + v + '">'));
                  });
                  $('body').append(form);

                  setTimeout(function(){
                    form.submit();
                    resolve(true);
                }, 1000);              
              }
          } else {
            reject(false);
          }
        };
        xhr.onerror = function () {
          reject(false);
        };
        xhr.send();
      });
    }


    callRequest()
    .then(function (res) {
        console.log('result : ',  res);
        if(res) {
            windowPopup.close();
        } 
    })
    .catch(function (err) {
      console.error('error : ', err);
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. Is there any other solution without using any third party library?

Comment: yeah look into link in the comment that uses native `XMLHttpRequest ` for firing `xhr` request. so you no need `jquery`. if you are asking for `promise` then its native js code not 3rd party.

Comment: how it can be achieved using http request?

Comment: Your solution works fine in HTML5 but unfortunately my application is using HTML 4. Can you please suggest anything else in this case?

Comment: I have replaced your code with JS XMLHttpRequest but still getting issue. Can you please send chat link so that I could tell you exact issue